# R data frame transformation values as names

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation, reshape

I'd like to do the following data transformation in R

```
Name Value
type1 value1.1
type2 value2.1
type3 value3.1
type1 value1.2
type2 value2.2
type3 value3.2
type1 value1.3
type2 value2.3
type3 value3.3
```

should become:

```
       Name Value1 Value2 Value3
type1 value1.1 value1.2 value1.3
type2 value2.1 value2.2 value2.3
type3 value3.1 value3.2 value3.3
```

I've been looking into the cast command, but I can't see a way to do this :(

If anybody could help, I'd be very grateful :)

Comment: Are we to presume that "value1.1" is just a placeholder for an actual value? Or do you really have a table with values such as "value1.1", "value2.1" and so on.

Comment: Some feedback on the answers below would be appreciated....

Answer (score 4):

Could try something like (if `df` is your data set)

```
df$Value2 <- paste0("Value", gsub("^.*\\.", "", df$Value)) # Creating an index column
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Name ~ Value2, value.var = "Value")
#    Name   Value1   Value2   Value3
# 1 type1 value1.1 value1.2 value1.3
# 2 type2 value2.1 value2.2 value2.3
# 3 type3 value3.1 value3.2 value3.3
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are lacking a unique "Id" variable.

You can use `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package for that, and then `dcast.data.table` to do the reshaping:

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast.data.table(getanID(mydf, "Name"), Name ~ .id, value.var = "Value")
#     Name        1        2        3
# 1: type1 value1.1 value1.2 value1.3
# 2: type2 value2.1 value2.2 value2.3
# 3: type3 value3.1 value3.2 value3.3
```

Comment: (+1) that is a nice one. Though not sure how your `getanID` function identified the pattern here without `gsub`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, my assumption is actually that "value1.1" and so on is just dummy placeholder text for actual values. `getanID` is like `sequence(.N)` for whatever has been specified as the existing "Id" (`"Name"` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a good site that explains the cast function in more detail: [An Introduction to reshape2](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html)

Using this, I've done the following:

```
mydata$Number <- rep("Value1", "Value2", "Value3", each=3)
dcast(mydata, Name~Number, value.var="Value")
```

This seems to work for me :)

Comment: This is certainly right. But @David's answer is more generalised. You will find his answer more welcoming for larger dataset.

Comment: @KFB, what do you mean about "more welcoming for larger dataset"?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I guess he means he won't need to write many different column names manually